# Unity выбивает ошибку

Tags: c#

Unity выбивает ошибку

> Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'Pozition' and no accessible extension method 'Pozition' accepting a first argument of type 'Rigidbody2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Вот код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercntrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 20f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    void Start()
    {

        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float moveX = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

        rb.MovePozition (rb.Pozition + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime );

    }
}
```

Говорит, что ошибка здесь:
`rb.MovePozition (rb.Pozition + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime );`
Я только начал кодить и не понимаю, в чём ошибка. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `rb.MovePosition`

Comment: `position` -c маленькой буквы.. первое - смотрите всегда мануал  https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html . Второе - пользуйтесь автокомплитом в IDE. К тому же не Po**z**ition  а Po**s**ition. Аналогично с `MovePozition`

Answer (score 0):

Замените строчку

```
rb.MovePozition (rb.Pozition + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime );
```

на строчку

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.Position + Vector2.right * moveX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Ошибка в слове Position